# Wrong e-mail recipient from SE

Tags: support, bug

I received an e-mail from SE, titled **"Please take the new Moderator Engagement survey"**.

But this survey is to be completed by moderators only, as is evident from the questions in the "Background Information" section.

Where did you buy your e-mail lists, I wonder...anyway, just to let the SE crew know and fix this.

Comment: Well now I dont feel so special :P

Comment: I just got a "sorry we goofed" e-mail. Apparently, the survey is not even for all moderators, only for Stack Overflow ones.

Comment: It's for all moderators across the network. In the case of the email, "Stack Overflow" is the company, not the site. :) Sorry about the email error!